# Centering first row of table + vertical line after first row

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, columns

I would like to have a table where the cell content of the first table row is centered. Then I would like to have a separator line between both columns starting from the second row. I have also managed something, however I would be interested if there is a better and nicer way. However, centering the first row with \centering unfortunately only worked for the first column.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\caption{Table}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{ m{7.5cm} m{7.5cm} }  
        \hline
       \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
        \textbf{Column1}     &    \textbf{Column2}      \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
 \begin{tabular}{ m{7.5cm} | m{7.5cm} }
    Text Here   & Text Here  \\ \hline
    Text Here   & Text Here 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}%[H]
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\caption{Table}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{7.5cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{7.5cm} }  
        \hline
       \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
        \textbf{Column1}     &    \textbf{Column2}      \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
 \begin{tabular}{ m{7.5cm} | m{7.5cm} }
    Text Here   & Text Here  \\ \hline
    Text Here   & Text Here 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with a single `tabular`:

```
\begin{tabular}{ m{7.5cm} | m{7.5cm} }  
        \hline
       \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column1}}     &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column2}}      \\ \hline \hline
    Text Here   & Text Here  \\ \hline
    Text Here   & Text Here 
\end{tabular}
```